# Subtract the lowest number from the given array

Tags: c#

What should I do if I want to remove a charge from the bill(myCharges)? In particular, I am supposed to remove the smallest charge from the bill (adjusting the total) and display the subtracted charge with the text “Charge Removed” followed by the new total.

I have no idea how to subtract lowest myCharges.

```
double[] myCharges = {20, 33.89, 84, 61.55} ;
double total = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < myCharges.Length; i++)
{
  total += myCharges[i];
}

Console.WriteLine("Total of MyCharges are {0:C}",total);

Console.WriteLine( "Charge Removed" , newtotal ) ;
Console.WriteLine( "Average of MyCharges are {0:C}" , myCharges.Average().ToString("0.00") ) ;
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ and Lambda. Then the solution is:

```
double[] myCharges = { 20, 33.89, 84, 61.55 };

Console.WriteLine("Total of MyCharges are {0:C}", myCharges.Sum());

// Here is the trick: remove the smallest charge from the bill<br />
myCharges = myCharges.Where(n => n != myCharges.Min()).ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("New Total After Smallest Charge Removed {0:C}", myCharges.Sum());
Console.WriteLine("Average of MyCharges are {0:C}", myCharges.Average().ToString("0.00"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Enumerable.Min` is faster (`O(N)`) than `OrderBy` (`O(N*logN)`) so you may use it if you need special case just minimal value:

```
var totalMinusSmallestCharge = myCharges.Sum() - myCharges.Min();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var lowestCharge = myCharges.OrderBy(n => n).First();
var totalWithoutLowestCharge = total - lowestCharge;
```

Comment: i didn't understand n =>n . what i should write according to my code

Comment: You should be able to use it as is. "n" is just the name of the variable I used in this lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add up all the charges except the smallest one, you can order your charges smallest to largest, then add up all but the first (smallest) one:

```
var totalMinusSmallestCharge
    = myCharges.OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(1).Sum();
```

If you then decided you wanted to add up all but the smallest two charges (for example), you could do this with a simple change:

```
var totalMinusSmallestTwoCharges
    = myCharges.OrderByDescending(x => x).Skip(2).Sum();
```

I'm not sure if you'll be "allowed" to use this, since this may be an assignment. However, LINQ is incredibly useful in the real world. You can [read more about it here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

Answer (score 0):

It might be more interesting (and more object oriented) to create a Charge class that has the following methods:

1. addCharge(float charge)   // no name with charge from your current data
2. float getTotalCharges()
3. removeCharge(float charge) // remove an entry from the charges with the same value

If you create a Class to represent the charges, then you can focus on all the behavior you want to add or adjust in just one place.  Then you can use that behavior from other classes (like your "main" method).

Comment: I am not allowed to add methods